# How to delete contents excluding formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hereunder my vba code which "works" : each time the file is opened, the zones for input are re-initialised, but I have one cell which is a vertical ref to another and I would like to keep the formula in.

Is there a way to delete only the values but not the formulae ?
Many thanks for your tips :-)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Bonjour, Vous êtes bien sur le formulaire ECHANTILLONS à facturer ou à rembourser"
Call Effacercontenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Union(Range("C8"), Range("C10:C11"), Range("C13:C20"), Range("B25:D25"), Range("B33"), Range("B40"))
For Each cell In myRange
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Vérifiez les cellules non remplies")
    End If
Next cell
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Effacercontenu()

Dim myRange As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("C8,C10:C11,C13:C20,D19:D20,C25:D25,B33:H33,B40:H40").ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Exclude that cell fromm here: `ActiveSheet.Range("C8,C10:C11,C13:C20,D19:D20,C25:D25,B33:H33,B40:H40").ClearContents`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Method SpecialCells

[image]

```
Sub ClearOnlyValues()
 Dim rngArea As Range

 'identify only numbers
 Set rngArea = Sheet1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
 
 'look at immeadiate window
 Debug.Print rngArea.Address
 
 'clear it
 rngArea.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I will try this function.